# How to enumerate through the DataTables of a DataSet starting at the second table in the collection using C#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, enumeration, code-readability

A for loop starting at index 1 is an obvious answer. I'm sure there are many other ways to do this. But what is the most readable way?

The question is using C# 4.0. LINQ is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ds.Tables.OfType<DataTable>().Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(ACTION);
```

Comment: This one looks good. However it hink you need to specify the generic type in OfType. So that means ds.Tables.OfType<DataTable>.Skip(1). I also think depending on the ACTION, it's better to have it in a foreach(DataTable dt in...). What do you think?

Comment: you are right...It's actually in there, but the editor strips out anytinhg between angle brackets for some reason.  I'll try putting it in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
dataset.DataTables.Skip(1)
```

Comment: DataTableCollection does not implement IEnumerable<T>, so you can't apply the Skip extension method directly to it.